# Bubble sort 2d array is incorrect

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to bubble sort the side diagonal of the matrix by decline, but the elements displayed are wrong. The problem is in indexes, but I do not know how to solve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main () {
    double a[100][100];
    int n, m;
    int i, j, b, c;
    srand (time (NULL));
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    scanf ("%d", &m);
    for (  i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (  j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 0.09 * (rand () %1000) - 0.5;
        }
    }
    printf ("Array A[N][M]: \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf ("\n");
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf ("%6.0f", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("\nElements of the right diagonal are: \n");
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf( "%6.0lf", a[n - j - 1][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("\n Sorted array A[N][M]:");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < (m-1); j++)
        {
            if (a[n - j - 1][j]<a[n-j][j+1])
            {
                int temp = a[n - j - 1][j];
                a[n - j - 1][j] = a[n-j][j+1];
                a[n-j-2][j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf ("\n");
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf ("%6.0f", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\nElements of the right diagonal are: \n");
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf( "%6.0lf", a[n - j-2][j+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is receiving a result of elements of diagonal sorted by a decline:
(example)

```
0.74   4.35   7.05     9.1   6.46     6.6   7.48
   5.41   7.28   4.85     2.8   4.28   7.47   7.87
   5.83   2.73   9.42   7.14   1.38   7.22   1.21
   6.91     3.8   9.51   4.56   8.74   7.43   5.63
   9.65   8.04   1.02   9.71   6.02   5.61   1.15
   2.35   1.04   2.23   4.43   6.45     4.5   4.31
     2.7   5.79   3.33   8.44   6.99   4.79        1
Diagonal :    7.48   7.47   1.38   4.56   1.02   1.04    2.7
Sorted array:
   0.74   4.35   7.05     9.1   6.46     6.6   7.48
   5.41   7.28   4.85     2.8   4.28   7.47   7.87
   5.83   2.73   9.42   7.14   4.56   7.22   1.21
   6.91     3.8   9.51     2.7   8.74   7.43   5.63
   9.65   8.04   1.38   9.71   6.02   5.61   1.15
   2.35   1.04   2.23   4.43   6.45     4.5   4.31
   1.02   5.79   3.33   8.44   6.99   4.79        1
Diagonal :   7.48   7.47   4.56    2.7   1.38   1.04   1.02
```

Hope for your help!

I managed to try the method given in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqzNgaFQEh8, but didn't succeed

Comment: Instead of random data you might consider using fixed data so you could see what's happening and perhaps figure out how to fix it. It would help to have a known solution when you step through the code in a debugger so you can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling this as C? `#include <cmath>` is C++.

Comment: @Retired Ninja
Thank you, I changed it to #include <math.h>, but the situation hasn't changed. Unfortunately, I can't change it to fixed data, because of the task condition

Comment: The task condition isn't really important as long as your algorithm is broken. Once you have the right algorithm you can replace the fixed data with random and it should still work. I don't know what your actual goal is, but perhaps this helps: https://godbolt.org/z/bcxf18cTE

Comment: When asking debugging questions, you should prepare a [mre]. To start, remove the randomness and the user input and find the smallest case that demonstrates the problem. This can be done with `m` and `n` set to 2, instead of read from input. Then, with only two elements on the diagonal, execution of the program is short enough that you can step through it in a debugger to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil
thank you, I will edit my post

Comment: Lvrnnk, Note this code `int temp = a[n - j - 1][j];  a[n - j - 1][j] = a[n-j][j+1]; a[n-j-2][j+1] = temp;` is not a swap.  Was that intended?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica I thought it is a swap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has at least these problems:

**Not a swap**

Mis-coded swap

```
            int temp = a[n - j - 1][j];
            a[n - j - 1][j] = a[n-j][j+1];
            // a[n-j-2][j+1] = temp;
            a[n-j][j+1] = temp;
```

**Output format**

If the goal is to see values to 2 decimal places, (and in columns of 7) use `"%7.2g"` or `"%7.2f"`, not `"%6.0f"`.

Rather than print a `'\n'` before a loop, I recommend afterwards.

```
    // printf ("\n");  // Delete
    for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf ("%6.0f", a[i][j]);
    }
    // Add
    printf ("\n");
```